# What is the correct way to use authorization policy class to authorize access to an index page in cakephp4?

Tags: authorization, cakephp-4.x

I developed a few cakephp3 apps, and now I'm learning how to use cakephp4. I'm trying to centralize all my authorization logic in the *Policy classes. I have a situation where a user wants to access a entity/index page, and I want to validate if he can access this index page by doing some queries.

So right now I'm using `$this->Authorization->authorize($this->Entity->newEmptyEntity());` in the controller, in order to be able to access an `EntityPolicy->canIndex()` method. Is there a more elegant way to do it, to call a policy method without an instance of the entity?

After that, in order to be able to run my queries, I'm using the ModelAwareTrait in the class, and querying data in a similar way that I do in controllers. Is there a better approach?

Comment: You should probably first figure out how you want to apply authorization and how you want to tell the user about denying access, ie do you want to manually check via `can()` and display your index action without data (ie you just want to deny access to some specific data), or do you want authorization be applied more or less automatically before the action is accessed, and have an exception thrown, so that the action cannot be accessed at all?

Comment: In most cases I want to go the second way: Apply it before the action.

Answer (score 2):

Send the entity itself. For example, if you are using the Articles controller

> $this->Authorization->authorize($this->Articles);
>
> $this->Authorization->can($this->Articles,'index')

While declaring the canIndex() method normally in your Policy.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was somewhat different (and easier I guess)

```
//In my ProjectController.php
  public function index()
  {
    $project = new Project();
    $this->Authorization->authorize($project);
  }
```

this way I don't have to do a useless query (I just create an empty Project object), but at the same time I can check the user attributes.
In my case the solution proposed by @eos (above) didn't work, because calling

```
    $this->Authorization->authorize($this->Projects);
```

lead to an unwanted result.